# Cryptowall encryption files

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ransomware

This is a question concerning the way the Cryptowall ransomware encrypts files on the victim's computer.

Someone knows if it is possible to recover the encryption key comparing the encrypted file and the original one (the same file without encryption)?

Comment: if its actually encrypted, no. if its a cipher yes you can figure it out, it may take some work but its doable.

Comment: No, this would be called a known-plaintext attack and most modern encryption algorithms (such as those used by Cryptolocker) are not known to be vulnerable to it.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Cryptowall encrypts all your data using AES, with a randomly generated key. That key is encrypted with an RSA public key, for which the bot controller holds the private key. When you pay the ransom, they decrypt the AES key using their private RSA key, which allows them to decrypt all your files.

This particular type of malware is particularly insidious and effective due to the fact that people rarely back up their data, and there's otherwise no way to recover the data without paying up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this site . You can upload a file and then they can provide a private key that could decrypt it

**https://www.fireeye.com/blog/executive-perspective/2014/08/your-locker-of-information-for-cryptolocker-decryption.html**

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.